# Create a timer at the bottom of the page in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I started using pygame and I want to do simple game.Now how can I add a timer to the game screen that displays the elapsed time of the game in seconds?

Image of the game screen:

[image]

code in github:

https://github.com/kidscancode/pygame_tutorials/blob/master/shmup/shmup-11.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pygame, there is a couple ways to get the current game time

- Use **time.time()** to get the time difference between two times
- Use **pygame.time.get_ticks()** to get milliseconds since `pygame.init()`

You only need to add a few lines of code to get the timer

```
import time # add this line
....
running = True
start_time = time.time() # game start - add this line
while running:
    ......
    draw_text(screen, str(score), 18, WIDTH / 2, 10)
    draw_text(screen, str(int(time.time() - start_time)), 18, 15, HEIGHT-20) # game timer - add this line
    draw_shield_bar(screen, 5, 5, player.shield)
```

Here's an easier solution requiring just one new line

```
draw_text(screen, str(score), 18, WIDTH / 2, 10)
draw_text(screen, str(int(pygame.time.get_ticks()/1000)), 18, 15, HEIGHT-20) # game timer - add this line
draw_shield_bar(screen, 5, 5, player.shield)
```